# Change highcharts mapbuble type to custom images

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to change the bubbles of highcharts mapbubble type to an image you have on your computer?

as in change the blue bubbles in this example:

```
type: 'mapbubble',
mapData: mapData,
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/map-bubble/

I would like to load a map marker instead of the circles but still based on the same data, how can i do that ?

Comment: The map marker should grow/shrink like the bubble?

Comment: No whats important is that the map marker is an image i want instead of bubble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mappoint` series, where you can set `series.marker.symbol` which can be image.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/x5r6or8b/1/

The only problem is that you need to get proper x/y coordinates for all points. I have generated this values by getting x/y of each bubble: http://jsfiddle.net/x5r6or8b/ and reusing this for demo.

Series code:

```
        series: [{
            name: 'Countries',
            mapData: mapData,
            color: '#E0E0E0',
            enableMouseTracking: false
        }, {
            type: 'mappoint',
            mapData: mapData,
            name: 'Population 2010',
            data: mapPoints,
            minSize: 4,
            maxSize: '12%',
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{point.code}: {point.z} thousands'
            },
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url(http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'
            }
        }]
```

Comment: Are the Highmaps types (like mappoint) and their options described in details somewhere? API seems to be lacking.

Comment: Oh, looks like [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#plotOptions.mappoint) are broken for mappoint. We will fix that, thanks! The rest of series-types are working properly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use mappoint, you can change the marker symbol in 'mapbubble' also. It will work fine.